# How to embed HTML inside awe.js Augmented Reality page

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, augmented-reality

I'm developing a Demo project using awe.js. It's a very good library (https://github.com/buildar/awe.js/tree/master) and I already created some good examples.
But now, I need to show a webpage when the application reconize a marker. I saw that it use Three.js Libraries but i am not able to configure the CSS3DRenderer and the other components. Is there someone that can help me?

Comment: Told this way your question is a bit broad : why can't you change the library itself and what do you need to configure ?

Comment: I found examples that explain how to show an image when a marker is recognized. But i would like to show a web page. I think that isn't needed to modify the library. I would like to discover how to use it. Is there anyone that know how to do?

Comment: I would directly ask on github at your place (don't hesitate to share the answer)